# DateTime.Compare in c#

Tags: c#, vb.net, operator-keyword

I am currently trying to convert a section of my vb.net code over to c# but I can't seem to get the syntax right.

my vb.net code is

```
Private Sub board(days As Integer, name As String)

Dim dcount As Integer = 0
Dim counter As Integer = 0


    If My.Computer.FileSystem.FileExists("pathway" + name) AndAlso Not File.ReadAllText("pathway" + name).Length = 0 Then

        Dim d As List(Of String) = File.ReadAllLines("pathway" + name).ToList
        Dim line As String = d(0)

        While counter <> d.Count
            line = d(counter)


            If DateTime.Compare(line.Substring(0, line.LastIndexOf(",")), Now.AddDays(days).ToString("MM/dd/yyyy")) < 0 Then
                dcount += 0
                counter += 1
            Else
                dcount += 1
                counter += 1

            End If
        End While
    End If
```

The vb.net code runs fine but my c# below gives me the error:

Operator '<' cannot be applied to operands of type 'string' and 'int'

The line the error is on is:

```
if (DateTime.Compare(line.Substring(0, line.LastIndexOf(",")), DateTime.Now.AddDays(days).ToString("MM/dd/yyyy") < 0)) {
```

the entire section is below

```
  private void board(int days, string name){


 int dcount = 0;
        int counter = 0;

if (File.Exists(@"pathway" + name) && File.ReadAllText(@"pathway" + name).Length != 0)
        {
            List<string> d = File.ReadAllLines(@"pathway" + name).ToList();
            string line = d[0];

            while (counter != d.Count)
            {
                line = d[counter];
                // compares the current date to the amount of days you put in the days integer
                if (DateTime.Compare(line.Substring(0, line.LastIndexOf(","), DateTime.Now.AddDays(days).ToString("MM/dd/yyyy") < 0) {
                    counter++;
                } else
                {
                    dcount++;
                    counter++;
                }
            }
        } 
 }
```

I appreciate any help you guys could give me

Comment: the code you provided is not even syntactically corrext. The line with the error misses at least one closing bracket... i guess after `line.LastIndexOf(",")`

Comment: also provide an example of a `line` please.

Comment: Try this ` if(DateTime.Compare(DateTime.Parse(line.Substring(0, line.LastIndexOf(","))), DateTime.Now.AddDays(days)) < 0)`. No idea if that will work for your data though, we don't know what line is.

Comment: there is a free Telerik tool online that you can use to convert VB to C# the only thing you have to do is change the `( )` around indexes to `[ ]` in C# code very straight forward

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`DateTime.Compare` can only be used to compare `DateTime` objects.

In VB.NET, there is implicit type conversion, but in c# you have to be explicit.

Instead of

```
if (DateTime.Compare(line.Substring(0, line.LastIndexOf(",")), DateTime.Now.AddDays(days).ToString("MM/dd/yyyy") < 0)) 
{
    //Do something
}
```

you will need to write something like

```
var d1 = DateTime.Parse(line.Substring(0, line.LastIndexOf(","));
var d2 = DateTime.Now.AddDays(days);
if (DateTime.Compare(d1, d2) < 0) 
{
    //Do something
}
```

If you really want it all on one line, you can do that, but it may be a touch hard to read:

```
if (DateTime.Compare(DateTime.Parse(line.Substring(0, line.LastIndexOf(",")), DateTime.Now.AddDays(days) < 0) 
{
    //Do something
}
```

Comment: Good answer. Like to add: why is the original poster using DateTime.Compare? Less than ("<") works fine.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! And what do you mean by that @ChiralMichael?

Comment: I mean, use `if ( d1 < d2 )  { ...`. It's equivalent to `if (DateTime.Compare( d1, d2 ) < 0) { ...`.  I strive to only use compare methods unless (1) I have a custom comparer, (2) I have a comparison type specified like `StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase` or (3) comparison operators are not defined on the type. None of these apply here. Moreover, I am so motivated because I find `<` much clearer.